# Tabla de MYSQL pesa DEMASIADO, teniendo solo 750K de registros

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas, tengo una tabla que me esta ocupando unos absurdos 32.2GB de espacio.
Dentro de esta tabla solo hay 3 columnas con texto, y nada más.

De la nada, esta tabla comenzó a aumentar su peso dramáticamente, empezando en 1GB, 5GB, 12GB y ahora va en 32GB sin siquiera entender porque.

Quizás sea algún problema de índices, o no se, la verdad es que no se.

Agregaré un tanto de información de phpmyadmin a ver si sirve de algo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Alguien tiene idea de que está sucediendo ???

Comment: Intenta `optimize table boleta_archivo;`

Comment: [Este post](https://www.forknerds.com/reduce-the-size-of-mysql/) puede ayudarte a resolver el problema en su totalidad. Lo primero de todo es que hagas un backup de tu BD y luego que hagas las verificaciones/optimizaciones allí recomendadas.

Comment: Puede tardar un poco, probablemente mas que el `max_execution_time` de php. Si puedes mejor usa una terminal y verifica con `show process list;` si continúa o terminó la optimización.

Comment: Te iba a decir justo lo que te acaba de sugerir @Sal, este tipo de operaciones es mejor ejecutarlas directamente en consola... es más yo ejecuto todas las operaciones de MySQL en consola, porque la interfaz de phpMyAdmin es insoportablemente lenta, incluso para consultas normales, más para esto, tratándose de una BD que ha crecido varios GB.

Comment: O si tienes MySQL Workbench.

Comment: En la terminal sólo teclea `mysql -p`. Te pedirá la contraseña, tecléala (no verás nada) y da intro/enter.

Comment: Es simple, checa la sesión de abajo en [esta liga](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hc0d3r/mysql-magic/demo/demo.gif). Me imagino que tu usuario no es root.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129926/discussion-between-sal-and-excorpion).